# Why JWT is invalid when signed with RSA C# .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, cryptography, jwt, salesforce, rsa

I want to create a JWT to be used with Salesforce Server-to-Server workflow.

this is the code used to generate the token.

```
public SalesforceJWT(string ClientID, string Username)
{
        this.ClientID = ClientID;
        this.Username = Username;
        header = "{\"alg\":\"RS256\"}";
        claims = "{\"iss\": \"" + ClientID + "\",\"sub\": \"" + Username + "\",\"aud\": \"" + aud + "\",\"exp\": \"" + exp + "\"}";

}


public string GenerateJWT()
{
    StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();
    token.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header)));
    token.Append(".");
    
    token.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(claims)));
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\OpenSSL\bin\certificate.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    var key = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
    
    byte[] signedString = key.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token.Replace("=", "").Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').ToString()), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    token.Append(".");
    token.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(signedString));
    return token.Replace("=", "").Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').ToString();
}
```

The problem is when I send the JWT to Salesforce, it says `invalid assertion` and when I added the token to the JWT website debugger, it says invalid signature.

Comment: JWT uses _Base64url_. Try replacing `token.ToString()` with `token.Replace("=", "").Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').ToString()`. But attention: `token.ToString()` is used twice and must be corrected at both places.

Comment: @Topaco so you mean any part where I convert token to string , I should replace the above before it ?

Comment: @Topaco I added your replace function before `tostring()` at the end of the program and `tostring()` at signing. but same issue

Comment: Check if a valid signature is determined here (https://jwt.io/) for RS256 if Base64url is applied (add for this the JWT and the public, but not the private key). Works on my machine when using my own key pair. You should also fix `claims` (does not compile) and add `header` (missing in the posted code).

Comment: @Topaco I updated my code above with the new Code you suggested and the claims and header so you can see them. you tried the above after the update and worked with you ?

Comment: Validation on https://jwt.io/ works. Of course this is only valid for my key pair and you have to check it yourself. In case of a rejection by Salesforce despite valid token there might be further issues.

Comment: @Topaco but when I copy the public key, private key or certificate to the secret part to verify, it says invalid too as if it cant read them.

Comment: @Topaco also i find the JWT says, it looks like you didnt encode with base64url correctly, the "=" must be omitted

Comment: For validation on https://jwt.io/, select RS256, delete the private key from the corresponding field (which is not needed for validation!) and insert the JWT and the public key into the corresponding fields. If the validation is not successful, this may not necessarily be due to the code (which generates a valid JWT on my machine), but could also indicate a problem with your keys.